# How do I count the number of SQL queries made to a H2 database using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

How do I count the number of SQL queries made to a H2 (1.3.172) database using Hibernate (4.3.11).

I just require a total count at the end of a long running task (several hours), I don't need a trace of the actual queries themselves.

Is there a simple way to do this, in theory I could do with either Hibernate or H2 but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article should help you out.

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-count-executed-queries-session/

In summary, you first need to add this property to your configuration.

```
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
```

Then, you have to add the following lines in your DAOs.

```
Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
long queryCount = stats.getQueryExecutionCount();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you know if there much performance hit if you had enabled all the time ?

Comment: So far, I have only use it in small queries, and the impact was not perceivable. Still, I would not be certain if that is the case in big queries.